# Layer disappears after adding overlapping layer to OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, overlapping-features

I created an OpenLayers map which links to my GeoServer WFS service. I tried to do the similar process as this [example](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/CuDYJe). However, when I moved my mouse onto the point, the original layer disappeared and nothing stayed on the map. Here is my JS code:

```
var container = document.getElementById('popup');
var content = document.getElementById('popup-content');
var closer = document.getElementById('popup-closer');

var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
  element: container,
  autoPan: true,
  autoPanAnimation: {
    duration: 250
  }
});

closer.onclick = function(){
  overlay.setPosition(undefined);
  closer.blur();
  return false;
}

var vectorSource2 = new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    url: function(extent) {
      return 'http://152.7.99.134:8080/geoserver/link_to_postgres/wfs?service=WFS'+ 
              '&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature'+
              '&typeName=link_to_postgres:a_1845disease0' +
             '&outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857' +  
             '&bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857';
    },
});

var pointLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource2,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
     image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 5,
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
              color: 'orange'
          }),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color:'grey',
            width: 0.5
          })
     })
  }),
});

var mapLayers = [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),

    pointLayer,
];

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  loadTilesWhileAnimating: true,
  loadTilesWhileInteracting: true,
    controls:[
        new ol.control.OverviewMap(),
        new ol.control.Zoom(),
        new ol.control.ScaleLine(),
    ],
    layers: mapLayers,
    overlays:[overlay],
    view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-25.922388,30.193475]),
    zoom: 3   
    })
});

function setContent(pointID,locationname, paragraph, status, comment){
  var popupContent = `<b>Ponit ID: `+ pointID + `</b>: ` + locationname + 
  `<br>` + paragraph + 
  `<br>
  <select id='status'>
  <option value='default' selected='selected' disabled>`+ status + `</option>
  </select><br>
  Comments: <input type='text' id='commentsOnPoint' placeholder="` + comment +`">&nbsp; 
  <button>Submit</button>`;
  return popupContent;
};

vectorSource2.on('change', function(evt){
  var source=evt.target;
  if(source.getState() === 'ready'){
  }
});

function generatePointsCircle(count, centerPixel) {
  var 
      radius = 25,
      twoPi = Math.PI * 2,
      start_angle = 0,
      circumference = radius * 2 * Math.PI,
      angleStep = twoPi / count,
      res = [],
      i, angle;

  for (i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    angle = start_angle + i * angleStep;
    res[i] = [
      centerPixel[0] + radius * Math.cos(angle), 
      centerPixel[1] + radius * Math.sin(angle)
    ];
  }
  return res;
};

var stroke = new ol.style.Stroke({color:[0,0,0,1]});
var fill = new ol.style.Fill({color:[255,255,255,1]});

var style_parada = [
  new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 5, fill: fill, stroke: stroke
    }),
    zIndex: 4
  })

];

var style_cluster = [
  new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 7, fill: fill, stroke: stroke
    }),
    zIndex: 14
  })
];

var style_cluster_hover = [
  new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 7, stroke: stroke,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({color:[46,52,54,1]})
    }),
    zIndex: 1
  })
];

map.on('singleclick', function(evt){
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature) {
    return feature;
  });
  if (feature){
    var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
    // This works
    var multiFeatures = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(evt.pixel);
    for ( i = 0; i < multiFeatures.length; i ++){
      f = multiFeatures[i]
      console.log(f.get('id') +':'+ f.get('matchednam'));
    };

    var pointID = feature.get('id');
    var locationname = feature.get('matchednam');
    var paragraph = feature.get('paragragh');
    var status = feature.get('status');
    var comment = feature.get('comment');

    container.innerHTML = setContent(pointID,locationname, paragraph, status, comment);

    overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
  } else {
    overlay.setPosition(undefined);
  }
});

map.on('pointermove', function(e) {
  if (e.dragging) {
      return;
  }
  var pixel = map.getEventPixel(e.originalEvent);
  var hit = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(pixel);

  e.map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
  // getViewport().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';

  if (hit) displayOverlapping(pixel);
});

var displayOverlapping = function(pixel) {

  var multift = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(pixel);
  // console.log(multift);
  if (multift.length > 1){
    var geom = multift[0].getGeometry(),
    coord = geom.getCoordinates(),
    px = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(coord),
    extent = [coord[0], coord[1], coord[0], coord[1]];

    console.log(multift);

    var points = generatePointsCircle(multift.length, px);

    multift[0].setStyle(style_cluster_hover);

    var sourceFeatures = new ol.source.Vector(),
        layerFeatures = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: sourceFeatures
    });

    var rows = [];

    multift.forEach(function(row, index){
      var cd_end = map.getCoordinateFromPixel(points[index]);

      row.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point(cd_end));
      row.setStyle(style_parada);

      rows.push(row);
    });

    sourceFeatures.addFeatures(rows);
    map.addLayer(layerFeatures);

  }
  };
```

I am pretty sure I got the features from the Sever because I can print out the features at pixel in the console window.

I am new to OpenLayers.